# Polymer - paper-input floating label color

Tags: html, css, dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

How can i change color of focused floating label in polymer?

[image]

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I was able to get around this issue was with this:

```
paper-input-decorator[focused] /deep/ .floating-label,
paper-input-decorator[focused] /deep/ .label-text {
/* floating label color when the input is focused */
color: orange !important;
}
```

Notice how it was necessary to type paper-input-decorator[focused] /deep/ twice

Answer (score 2):

You could also use core-style to do this if you didn't want to use the /deep/ selectors, it would look something like this (untested):

```
<core-style id="paper-input-decorator">
  .floating-label, .label-text {
    color: orange;
  }
</core-style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following polymer style variable: --paper-input-container-focus-color, for example

```
#myInput{
   --paper-input-container-focus-color: red;
}
```

Comment: this also changes the input bottom border unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

> For an Information:

To change any style of a **label** or **floating label** inside the **paper-input**, use the code below.

```
paper-input {
  --paper-input-container-label: {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
  };
  --paper-input-container-label-floating: {
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
  };
}
```